# Fix duplicate error sudo apt-get update .Help me!

Tags: 12.04, updates, security

I trying update security ...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And faiel...

Reading package lists ... Done

```
W: Duplicate sources.list http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise entry / i386 partner Packages 
(/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

How fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain duplicates.

Please do:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

and check for lines which are the same. If You need to use multiple components from one repository like:

`main, universe, multiverse or restricted`

You can add them as one line, example:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
```